# MS Project Printing a Gant chart

Tags: printing, microsoft-project-2010

How do I print a Gant chart in Project 2010 such that the timescale header matches what's on the screen?  I have tried using the page setup, but that doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by timescale header matches?  You cannot remove dates before or after in the timescale.  If the dates don't match - particularly the years - did you set fiscal year data?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I correctly understand your question, but it's possible to print Gantt chart for specific time range:

[image]